# Hadoop: Task Tracker won't start java.io.IOException

Tags: exception, hadoop, hdfs, java-io

I setup Hadoop, formatted the HDFS, ran bin/start-all.sh, ran bin/stop-all.sh and had no problems.

Now every time I run bin/start-all.sh, the Task Tracker fails to start and I get the following entry in my the Task Tracker log.

```
    2012-03-27 21:22:03,842 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9001 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1065)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1033)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$3.run(TaskTracker.java:708)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initialize(TaskTracker.java:704)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.(TaskTracker.java:1328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3430)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:175)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:128)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$PingInputStream.read(Client.java:343)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:712)

2012-03-27 21:22:03,843 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

I have found some references to this elsewhere, but have been unable to find a solution.  I must admit that I am new to Hadoop and honestly have no clue as to what this error is saying.

Any ideas or suggestions on things I can try would be greatly appreciated.  I hope that I have posted enough information, but not too much.  If more info is needed, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you confirmed that a job tracker is running on port 9001 for the local machine:

- Find the process id (pid) for the JobTracker (`jps -v or ps axww | grep JobTracker`)
- `netstat -atnp | grep ${pid}`
- Check the job tracker logs for any messages (`ls -l /proc/${pid}/fd` should list all the open files for the JobTracker, making location of the log file easier)

Comment: I did as you said and the job tracker is running.  However, it appears the name node is not running. The name node log has the following entry: 

`2012-03-28 08:26:03,873 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /mnt/home/wenderni/hadoop-0.20.203.0/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.`

This looks like a more serious problem than I had thought.

Comment: I never did find exactly what the problem was, but I had things really messed up.  In any case, I was using an Alpha release so I updated to the newest version and have reconfigured everything.  Please to say I'm having no problems now.  Thanks for the help, your answer helped me learn how to effectively use the Hadoop logs.